# possible memory leak by returning "local" heap-allocated object

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
int do_memory()
{
  int * empty_ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *empty_ptr = 5;
  return *empty_ptr;
}
...
int b = do_memory();
free(&b); //obviously not valid
```

When `b` goes out of scope, I would be right in assuming the memory in empty_ptr still exists? But is impossible to free and therefore this is bad code?

Comment: "When b goes out of scope, I would be right in assuming the memory in empty_ptr still exists?" Yes. "But is impossible to free and therefore this is bad code?" Yes again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "int *empty_ptr" (the pointer to the allocated memory block) is never released, you just get the return value from do_memory.

If you want no leaks, use this

```
int* do_memory()
{
  int * empty_ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *empty_ptr = 5;
   return empty_ptr;
}
...
int* b = do_memory();
int b_local = *b;
free(b); // valid
```

or this (no leaks, no allocations except the var on stack, no performance hit):

```
void do_memory(int* RetValue)
{
  *RetValue = 5;
}
...
/// b is allocated locally on stack
int b;
do_memory(&b);
// no free() calls are needed
```

Comment: I think I understand how malloc works now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function signature is wrong, update it to:

```
int* do_memory()
{
  // code
}

...

int* b = do_memory();

// At this point, freeing b is valid and will 
// release the resources previously allocated in do_memory()
free(b); // valid
```

However, if you don't `free(b)` and the function finishes, it will destroy variable `b` without releasing the previously allocated memory block. This will render a memory leak since you no longer have a reference to that memory block to disallocate: bad, bad code!

Comment: +1, but in C a real prototype (and not only a declaration) would be `int* do_memory(void)`.